# How to store MYSQL_FETCH_ARRAY result into different Variables

Tags: php, arrays, resultset

I am unable to find a solution for a simple problem, it's a shame. After using mysql select statement, let say I get two records, what I want to do is to store these results into two different variables. Let say, I get 4,5 after select statement. I want to save 4 and 5 into different variables.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT test_id FROM test WHERE MONTH(created)='$res_month'");

while($abc = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    echo $abc; 

}
```

Comment: Replaced some of the tags with more relevant ones. In particular, your question is about PHP and not about MySQL, so I replaced the product tag accordingly.

Comment: Please use mysqli or PDO instead, as mysql_* is insecure and deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Push the records to an array like this:

```
$data = array();
while($abc = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data[] = $abc;
}

$first = $data[0]['test_id'];
$second = $data[1]['test_id'];
// etc ...
```

You can use a foreach to access your data:

```
foreach($data as $value){
    //$value
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. Your code works perfectly. I thinks i need practice. I have not touched PHP for last 6 months.

Comment: If you use `array_push()` to add one element to the array it's better to use `$array[] =` because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function. From [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT test_id FROM test WHERE MONTH(created)='$res_month'");
$a = array();
while($abc = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$a[] = $abc['test_id']; 
}
```

To access values

```
foreach($b as $a){
     echo $b;
 }
```

Don't use mysql_* function, as they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Keys of array from mysql_fetch_array are always field names from table.
Every loop you push a new line from query result.

As aaron says you can conserve it pushing values into array.
You can do it with a two dimension array too if table have a primary key.
This way you can find lines by index.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT test_id,field2,field3 FROM test WHERE MONTH(created)='$res_month'");


$data=array();
while($abc = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{

// two dimension array

     $data[$abc['test_id']]['test_id']=$abc['test_id'];
     $data[$abc['test_id']]['field2']=$abc['field2'];
     $data[$abc['test_id']]['field3']=$abc['field3'];

// view values

     echo $abc['test_id']; 
     echo $abc['field2']; 
     echo $abc['field3']; 
}
```